# Find zeros of a transcendental function

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

*Mathematica* 10 can not give me solution of this equation

```
NSolve[τ - ArcCos[1/(-11.` + 6.16949` E^(0.05` τ))]/Sqrt[
   0.380626` + (
    0.08062600000000003` - 
     0.04130349999999999` E^(0.05` τ))/(-1.` + 
     1.` E^(0.05` τ) - 0.25` E^(0.1` τ))] == 0, τ ]
```

That's running too long time. Is there a way to have an alternative issue.

Any help is welcome

Comment: FindRoot works well for such equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun = t - ArcCos[1/(-11. + 6.16949 E^(0.05 t))]/
   Sqrt[0.3806 + (0.080626 - 0.0413035 E^(0.05 t))/
      (-1. + 1. E^(0.05 t) - 0.25 E^(0.1 t))];
```

To get a "feeling" for the function we first plot it. We find a reasonable
plot range with `FunctionDomain`.

```
FunctionDomain[fun, t]

13.3062 < t < 13.8629 || t > 13.8629 || t < 9.65863

Plot[fun, {t, -5, 14}]
```

[image]

There are three zeros which we find by mapping `FindRoot` over the range:

```
(sol = FindRoot[fun == 0, {t, #}] & /@ Range@12) // TableForm
```

[image]

We get rid of the "duplicates" (values with very small differences) and chop the imaginary parts with

```
uni = Union[Chop@sol[[All, 1, 2]], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.1 &)]
```

> {4.51773, 8.36369, 11.5824}

The zero-points are

```
p = Point@Transpose[{uni, ConstantArray[0, Length@uni]}];
```

Let's plot them

```
Plot[fun, {t, -5, 14}, Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, Red, p}]
```

[image]

Comment: Since you're using `Plot[]` already: you can use `Mesh` + `MeshFunctions` for finding the roots; search the site for examples of this.

Comment: Thanks, very handy - it's even in the documentation :)

Answer (score 5):

Problems such as this can be solved using Ted Ersek's [RootSearch](http://,).  After it has been installed according to the instructions at the location just given, execute

```
Needs["Ersek`RootSearch`"];
Quiet@RootSearch[τ - ArcCos[1/(-11.` + 6.16949` E^(0.05` τ))]/
    Sqrt[0.380626` + (0.08062600000000003` - 0.04130349999999999` E^(0.05` τ))/
    (-1.` + 1.` E^(0.05` τ) - 0.25` E^(0.1` τ))] == 0, {τ, -5, 14}]
(* {{τ -> 4.51724}, {τ -> 8.36432}, {τ -> 11.5824}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

`NSolve` can be quite powerful when you give it a finite domain:

```
NSolve[τ - 
    ArcCos[1/(-11.` + 6.16949` E^(0.05` τ))]/
     Sqrt[0.380626` + (0.08062600000000003` - 
          0.04130349999999999` E^(0.05` τ))/(-1.` + 
          1.` E^(0.05` τ) - 0.25` E^(0.1` τ))] == 0 && 
  0 < τ < 15, τ]
(*  {{τ -> 4.51724}, {τ -> 8.36432}, {τ -> 11.5824}}  *)
```

Comment: I'm sure this has come up before on the site, but today I can't find a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

```
In[4]:= FindRoot[τ - 
   ArcCos[1/(-11.` + 6.16949` E^(0.05` τ))]/
    Sqrt[0.380626` + (0.08062600000000003` - 
         0.04130349999999999` E^(0.05` τ))/(-1.` + 
         1.` E^(0.05` τ) - 0.25` E^(0.1` τ))] == 0, {τ, 1}]

Out[4]= {τ -> 4.51724}
```