# Probleme with Ted Ersek's RootSearch package

Tags: equation-solving, packages

The following question is   a logical continuation of this [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100068/find-zeros-of-a-transcendental-function). The Ted Ersek's RootSearch package doesn't work with this code:

```
Needs["Ersek`RootSearch`"];
Quiet@RootSearch[τ - ArcCos[1/(-11.` + 6.16949` E^(0.05` τ))]/
Sqrt[0.380626` + (0.08062600000000003` - 0.04130349999999999` E^(0.05` τ))/
(-1.` + 1.` E^(0.05` τ) - 0.25` E^(0.1` τ))] == 0, {τ, -5, 14}]
```

with  error message:

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open Ersek`RootSearch`. >>
Needs::nocont: Context Ersek`RootSearch` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>
```

Thank's for help!

Comment: You don't have the package installed, go to [this page](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) and download the .m file and the example notebook.  The notebook has a section on installation and will help you find out where to put the file.

Comment: *Mathematica*  cannot open the file. Closely related (just for a different package): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28268/131. Tip: search the site for "was not created when Needs" or similar.

Comment: On a related note, I installed the package and I get the error about setting the minprecision to negative infinity.  I follow Jens's advice in the comment to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16442/9490) and replace the negative infinity by positive infinity in the package, and it now crashes my kernel.

Comment: Consider using any of the listed alternatives in the linked duplicate instead, so that you don't need to load an external package.